# Unluckiest character in Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata

Who according to you is the unluckiest character in epic Mahabharata? Some say it's Karna, but according to me it is Dhitrashtra, as he could not see Lord Krishna himself with his very own eyes before him!

Comment: **For me,** it's Pitamah Bhishma and Karna.

Comment: It's Draupadi. She lost almost everything. She was assaulted and insulted in the sabha. Her father and her entire Panchala royal family died in the war. All of her sons were brutally murdered.

Comment: from a purely soteriological perspective, the most unlucky character in Mahabharat is obviously Krsna.  He is blamed for war, and then cursed to lose all his community.  He cannot pray or do penance, b/c he happens to be god himself :(